# Why games claimed to be compatible with 3rd Gen iPod won't run on my 3rd Gen iPod 8GB?

Tags: ipod-touch, games, ios

I have an iPod touch 3rd Gen 8GB capacity MC086 model which was purchased from an Authorized reseller. I purchased several games from iTunes on my PC which was compatible with iOS 4.0/4.1/4.2.1 and iPod 3rd/4th Generation. However when I installed the games, they were *revoked by iTunes* with **"NOT COMPATIBLE"** message. I found that I will put those games to waste if I don't install it.

My question is :

- How could it possible that a **3rd Gen iPod** won't be compatible with games that was supposed to be supported the device ?

I've tried jailbreaking and used iFunbox, yet I still failed. Neither legal way nor illegal one would solve my problem. Any help or explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What model iPod does Apple's serial number look up tell you you have? http://support.apple.com/manuals/#

Answer (score 4):

They never actually made an 8GB iPod Touch 3rd Generation. What they did was lower the price of the 8GB iPod Touch from 229 to 199 and sold it along side the actual 3rd Generation 32GB and 64GB iPod Touches of that year.

Technically what you hold in your hand is an iPod Touch 2nd Generation. You're not the first person to notice these kinds of things, especially since there was a lot of confusion at Apple and 3rd Party Retailers when it came to selling this device.

A lot of people around the internet have the same issue when it comes to software and when it comes to what Generation it actually is.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2777426?start=0&tstart=0

http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110111210334AAlplU9

http://www.ifans.com/forums/threads/2g-or-3g-which-do-i-have.251593/

Sorry that it won't work and for all the confusion.  I hope that this information helps you out.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I recommend you to read these threads to gain knowledge about what problem you're facing:

- [WHich 8GB iPod touch does support iOS 5](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55180/which-8gb-ipod-touch-do-not-support-ios-5?rq=1) and it seems you were another victim to this confusion thing. You should be able to find out why your iPod unit won't run new games and its evidences.
- [Trying to get things clear with iPod touch 3rd Gen 8GB](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54866/trying-to-get-things-clear-with-ipod-touch-3rd-gen-8gb-mc-model?rq=1), here it's more about argument between stores and misled customers.

After you get some ideas, you should've realized by now that you've purchased and owned a true 2nd Gen iPod MC model - *commonly advertised as 3rd Gen 8GB iPod around the globe*.

If you need another evident, go to apple website and register your product with your **iPod's serial number** and you'll find out that you got a *refurbished* 2nd Gen iPod.
You should also watch Phil Schiller iPod touch presentation September 2009 from youtube, and you'll see 2 things stated by **de_an777** :

- Phil Schiller wiped out the $229 from the screen and changed it into $199 after he said that $199 is the price point that Apple would give to the 8GB model.
- Then he brings up the iPod touch lineup, changed the price of the 8GB model, and doubled the capacity for the 16&32 GB models. He said," there are two other things about the 32&64 GB versions of the iPod touch, and **I'll make sure you knew about it**."
- The first thing was those large capacity models would operate with up to 50% faster and the second was those models were added OpenGL ES 2.0 support.
- But still, he did not say anything about upgrade to 8GB model, which means, it will be the same as the previous model (at that time, Apple hadn't classified iPods into generations yet).

These information were also released in apple press release 09/2009, basically telling you the same thing.

At this point, there's nothing you can do about it. However, in those 2 threads I've posted here, many people take action to the stores (either authorized or 3rd party ones) because they believe that they were misled during the time of the purchase. If you think you were misled too (such as, the seller said that all 3 3rd Gen models offers the same capability), I think you may take action too.

Comment: When Phil Schiller said "I'll make sure you knew about it", it was probably to emphasize that people should already know that 8GB models was totally different from the 32&64GB models. Then stores too should've advertised them as such, not misleading  customers around the globe by stating they were all the same iPods.

Answer (score 1):

Did you purchased that iPod because you were convinced by the store that it had the same performance as the real 3rd Gen iPod ?

If it's a "yes", I'm afraid you've been duped by the seller.

No matter what you answer might be, here's the fact :

- iPod touch 8GB in late 2009 is an *updated* version of the iPod touch in late 2008
- iPod touch 32/64GB in late 2009 is a *new* version of no previously released iPod

As you can see in picture below (it was Apple online store back in January 2010) :
[image]

- Apple had made no changes to the 8GB models except **updated its iOS to iOS3 for free**.
- But Apple made new 32GB iPods with **faster performance including gaming**.

Hence, this is the official advertisement made by Apple and I still confused why a lot of Authorized stores still making the same mistake since I'm victimized here too.

Finally, you iPod does not support gaming because it's not a 3rd Gen iPod, its an updated/refurbished/re-released iPod touch 2nd Gen.